# finite dimension representation of image

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, differential-topology

Suppose $f:D^n\to H$ a continuous(not necessarily linear) map, here $D^n$ the $n$.dimension disk, $H$ a infinite dimension hilbert space. I wonder if there exist a finite subset of basis ${e_1.…,e_n}$ of $H$ such that $Im f$ fall in the linear space span by ${e_1,…,e_n}$?

I'm trying to prove the space of irreducible connection is weak contractible by myself and I find I need  some techniques in classical differential topology, so I need to reduce this question to a finite dimension case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not true. Define $f:\{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}\to \ell^2$ by $f(1/n)=\frac 1n e_n$ (where $e_n$ form the standard basis) and extend, e.g., by Tietze's theorem (or affine linear to make it elementary) to $D^1=[-1,1]$. The image for $f$ has dense linear span.

Comment: @Jochen This should be an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by Paul Frost, I upgrade my comment to an answer:

That's not true. Define $f:\{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}\to
\ell^2$ by $f(1/n)=\frac 1n e_n$ (where $e_n$ form the standard basis) and extend continuously, e.g., by Tietze's theorem (or affine linear to make it elementary) to $D_1=[−1,1]$. The image of $f$ has dense linear span and is thus not contained in any finite dimensional subspace.